# Solution to $y''+(1-x)y'+y=0$ using power series, where $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have,
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n},\quad y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}, \quad y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2},$$
subbing these back into the original equation,
$$y''+(1-x)y'+y=0,$$
I obtain,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}=0,$$
Then I sub in $k=n-2$ and $k=n-1$ appropriately to get,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}x^{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}=0.$$
It is after this point in my calculation I get stuck, if anyone could show me where to go from where, or where I have gone wrong that would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try changing the "n"s in the last two sums to "k"s, and then you can combine all the sums into one big one. You can click "edit" below your question to show the results of this.

Comment: Check carefully the lower limits of summations after substitutions. And the next step is to put all coefficients with the same $x^k$ together and notice that $\{x^0,x,x^2,\dots\}$ are linearly independent and their linear combination is equal to zero.

Comment: I would also advise you to *also* try to solve it using a different method than the one recommended. For one thing - to be able to check the solution you've got; for the other - to be able to guess what (if anything) the final series converges to.

Comment: @mobiuseng, while those monomials are indeed linearly independent, one cannot deduce that the coefficients must vanish from their linear independence, as linear independence only applies to **finite** sums and not series.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez fair enough. So, what exactly is the line of reasoning to insist on these coefficients to be zero? I can think of a different explanation: function $f=0$ on RHS has a unique Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ with all coefficients being zero. If series on LHS is convergent, each finite sum must have zero coefficients. But this is kind of the same as $\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ being independent, except there must be a condition that would allow transition from finite to infinite set.

Comment: Indeed: one can eaily show that a power series which converges to the zero function has its oefficients all equal to zero. But this is not done using linear independence: one computes derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the correct path.
First let me confirm you that.

Keep in mind that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2}$$
Since the terms of the sum for $n=0,1$ are all $0$.

Hence, we can now sub $k=n-2$ and we get,
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}x^{k}$$

Similarly we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k}$$

Hence, the expression
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}=0,$$

finally becomes
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}x^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ka_{k}x^{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}=0$$

That is,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}+(k+1)a_{k+1}-ka_{k}+a_{k}\right]x^k=0$$

Then you solve the recurrence equation by equating the coefficients of $x^k$ on both sides.

$$(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}+(k+1)a_{k+1}+(1-k)a_{k}=0$$

This is a 3-term recurrence relation. So you need to have $2$ initial guesses, i.e. for $a_0$ and $a_1$.

And you have to proceed to find values for $a_k$ to find your solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, I have solved the recurrence and now have my solution.

Comment: @DanElsender You're welcome.

Comment: @DanElsender Well that recurrence relation looks pretty nightmarish, doesn't it? I would be genuinely interested what result(s) you've got.

Comment: @user8734617 Is it necessary to solve it though? For practical use, I would just start with known $a_0$ and $a_1$ (from initial values of the equation) and work out better approximations by calculating next $a_k$.

Comment: @DanElsender I don't know, depends how your problem is given. To me, it seems you are lucky if $a_0+a_1=0$ and not so lucky if $a_0+a_1\ne 0$.

Comment: @user8734617 By solving the recurrence relation I have the result, $$y(x)=a_{0}\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}x^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}x^{3}-\frac{2}{4!}x^{4}+...\right)+a_{1}\left(x-\frac{1}{2!}x^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}x^{3}-\frac{2}{4!}x^{4}+...\right)$$

Comment: @DanElsender Thanks!